# SQL view to join 3 tables, but there are multiple columns to use for the ON clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-view

We have a database in PostgreSQL we are using for battery information.

1. Materials (raw chemical materials)
2. Electrodes (which are cathodes or anodes) made from the raw materials
3. Cells that are made of Electrodes and Electrolytes (materials)

There is a Unique "Key" (first column) in each table to identify the item. So electrodes will point back to the materials. The issue is that there are both Cathodes and Anodes columns Cells table that refer to the Electrodes table (and binders, active materials, solvents, in the electrodes that point back to the materials).

My current view looks like this. But I know it is not correct:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW se3d.m2elect2cell AS
SELECT 
    m."Key" as "Mat Key",
    m."Chemical",
    m."Description" as "Material Description",
    e."Description" as "Electrode Description",
    e."Role" as "Electrode Role",
    c."Key" as "Cell Key",
    c."Description" as "Cell Description"
FROM se3d.materials m
    INNER JOIN se3d.electrodes e ON (e."Active Material" = m."Key")
    INNER JOIN se3d.cells c ON (c."Cathode" = e."Key")
```

The kind of queries we are looking for is finding all cells with a particular material property, or going from cell to find the materials used in its manufacture.

Definitions for the tables in question look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE se3d.materials
(
    "Key" character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "Chemical" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Description" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Created" date,
    "Created By" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Modified" date,
    "Modified By" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Version" double precision,
    "Chemical Type" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Storage" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Tags" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT materials_pkey PRIMARY KEY ("Key")
)

CREATE TABLE se3d.electrodes
(
    "Key" character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "Active Material" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Active Material mass (g)" double precision,
    "Binder" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Binder mass (g)" double precision,
    "Conductive Additive" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Carbon mass (g)" double precision,
    "Created" date,
    "Created By" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Creator" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Description" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Modified" date,
    "Modified By" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Role" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Solvent" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Solvent mass (g)" double precision,
    "Version" double precision,
    "Creation Date" date,
    "Tags" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT electrodes_pkey PRIMARY KEY ("Key")
)
CREATE TABLE se3d.cells
(
    "Key" character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "Creator" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Creation Date" date,
    "Electrolyte" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Anode" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Cathode" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Separator" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Form Factor" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Test Plan" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Description" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Created" date,
    "Created By" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Modified" date,
    "Modified By" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Version" double precision,
    "Tags" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT cells_pkey PRIMARY KEY ("Key")
)
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: Agreed. There are technical and business restraints that are there for the moment.

Comment: My view only merges in the Cathode ID, what about the Anode ID and what about the other fields that make relations between the tables?

Comment: I also just added two sample queries we want from the "merged" view. Don't worry about performance. Don't expect more than about a few hundred entries in each table.

Comment: can you give an example? and also I suspect INNER JOIN is wrong. Probably need LEFT and RIGHT joins depending on which way we are trying to go (or FULL JOIN?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you role play Electrode as Anode and Cathode...

```
SELECT 
    m."Key" as "Mat Key",
    m."Chemical",
    m."Description" as "Material Description",
    anode."Description" as "Anode Description",
    anode."Role" as "Anode Role",
    cathode."Description" as "Cathode Description",
    cathode."Role" as "Cathode Role",
    c."Key" as "Cell Key",
    c."Description" as "Cell Description"
FROM se3d.materials m
    INNER JOIN se3d.electrodes anode ON (anode."Active Material" = m."Key")
    INNER JOIN se3d.electrodes cathode ON (cathode."Active Material" = m."Key")
    INNER JOIN se3d.cells c ON (c."Cathode" = cathode."Key")
                            or (c."Anode" = anode."Key")
```

Comment: Works great. Given the two sample queries I listed from the VIEW can you tell me if INNERJOIN is correct, or should I be looking at LEFT, RIGHT, NATURAL or FULL?

Comment: It depends.  Which output fields would be allowed to have NULL values?

Comment: No nulls allowed

Answer (score 1):

> The kind of queries we are looking for is finding all cells with a particular material property, or going from cell to find the materials used in its manufacture.

You will probably not find one view to efficiently satisfy both of these uses.  You might need multiple views, or just write the queries you want directly and run them without views.

Comment: Yep. I expect not. But right now efficiency is not the goal. So would I do a FULL JOIN to go both ways, or have LEFT and RIGHT JOIN views so and then use them for queries that go from the right or left. (I don't expect more than 100 rows for now, so we can do performance once we have a better idea of the queries).